# Bash - Hiding command (preventing from bad manipulations)

Tags: shell, configuration, bash

I was wondering if they was a way to prevent some commands from being executed in order to prevent from bad manipulation sometimes (for exemple you execute "rm *.**py**" when you wanted to execute "rm *.**pyc**" or something like that).

People will say that it's the user's responsability to check his inputs and it's right but I would like to know anyway if there's a way.

For "basic" things, we can use aliases in our bashrc like :

```
alias apt-get="echo 'We use aptitude here !'"
alias sl="echo 'Did you mean ls ?'"
```

But for something with arguments like "rm -f *.py" (or "rm -Rf /"), this simple trick don't work.
Of course, I just want a basic method that prevent the exact command to be executed (same spaces and same arguments ordering would be a good start).

Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: Note that it is the shell that expands those wildcards, so your program or function would never actually *see* `*.py`. All it would see, was the result of globbing `*.py`, i.e. a list of files matching that pattern. (Or the literal `*.py` if there are none, or an empty string if `shopt -s nullglob`.)

Comment: It's a bad idea to rely on same-name replacements for things like `rm`. All it takes is for it to be unavailable just once and Bam! your files are gone because the safety net isn't there. If you want to work with a net, you should use different names (eg. "saferm").

Comment: @Dennis Williamson : Yes you're right, using different names is maybe better but not actually for your reason (at least if you use your "rm" command like the original one (without taking advantage directly of things like "rm * does not delete my source code so I can always use it")). But the problem is maybe more for Makefiles or install scripts that does not know that your "rm" is not a standard one and you can create huge side effects...

Comment: What I mean is that if you do `alias rm=rm -i`, for example, then do `rm *` thinking "what's the harm - it'll ask me first" and you start relying on that safety net - someday the alias won't be there and you won't get the opportunity to say "Y" or "N" and everything will be gone.

Comment: Questions are questions, and answers are answers. Please could you put your solution in an answer of its own, instead of in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use the time-honoured approach of putting one of your own path components in front of all the others:

```
PATH=~/safebin:$PATH
```

and then, in `~/safebin`, you put scripts that are "safer" like `rm`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for fspec in "$@" ; do
    if [[ "${fspec: -3}" = ".py" ]] ; then
        echo Not removing ${fspec}, use /bin/rm if you really want to.
    else
        echo Would /bin/rm "${fspec}" but for paranoia.
    fi
done
```

That script outputs for `rm *`:

```
Would /bin/rm chk.sh but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm go but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm go.sh but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm images but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm images_renamed but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm infile.txt but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm jonesforth.S but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm jonesforth.f but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm mycode.f but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm num1.txt but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm num2 but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm num2.txt but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm proc.pl but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm qq but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm qq.c but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm qq.cpp but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm qq.in but for paranoia.
Not removing qq.py, use /bin/rm if you really want to.
Would /bin/rm qq.rb but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm qq.s but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm qq1 but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm qq2 but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm qqq but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm rm but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm source.f90 but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm test.txt but for paranoia.
Would /bin/rm xx but for paranoia.
Not removing xx.py, use /bin/rm if you really want to.
```

Now obviously the `"${fspec: -3}" = ".py"` is a simplistic one and a black list. I'd probably prefer to have a white list of things I was allowed to delete and deny everything else.

---

And here's a white list version based on regular expressions:

```
#!/bin/bash

for fspec in "$@" ; do
    del=0
    if [[ ! -z "$(echo "${fspec}" | grep 'a.e')" ]] ; then
        del=1
    fi
    if [[ ! -z "$(echo "${fspec}" | grep '\.[Ss]$')" ]] ; then
        del=1
    fi

    if [[ ${del} -ne 1 ]] ; then
        echo "Not removing ${fspec}, use /bin/rm if you want."
    else
        echo "    Removing ${fspec}"
        #/bin/rm "${fspec}
    fi
done
```

which outputs:

```
Not removing chk.sh, use /bin/rm if you want.
Not removing go, use /bin/rm if you want.
Not removing go.sh, use /bin/rm if you want.
    Removing images
    Removing images_renamed
Not removing infile.txt, use /bin/rm if you want.
    Removing jonesforth.S
Not removing jonesforth.f, use /bin/rm if you want.
Not removing mycode.f, use /bin/rm if you want.
Not removing num1.txt, use /bin/rm if you want.
Not removing num2, use /bin/rm if you want.
Not removing num2.txt, use /bin/rm if you want.
Not removing proc.pl, use /bin/rm if you want.
Not removing qq, use /bin/rm if you want.
Not removing qq.c, use /bin/rm if you want.
Not removing qq.cpp, use /bin/rm if you want.
Not removing qq.in, use /bin/rm if you want.
Not removing qq.py, use /bin/rm if you want.
Not removing qq.rb, use /bin/rm if you want.
    Removing qq.s
Not removing qq1, use /bin/rm if you want.
Not removing qq2, use /bin/rm if you want.
Not removing qqq, use /bin/rm if you want.
Not removing rm, use /bin/rm if you want.
Not removing source.f90, use /bin/rm if you want.
Not removing test.txt, use /bin/rm if you want.
Not removing xx, use /bin/rm if you want.
Not removing xx.py, use /bin/rm if you want.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's maybe the best solution after all ! I might consider doing some scripting in python for more readability (and if I loose python, use directly /bin/rm) but your bash scripts seem to be well done !

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this http://code.google.com/p/safe-rm/

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the lesser-known command "command" (which is similar to the "builtin" command) to create a restrictive rm wrapper:

```
help builtin command | less

# test example using ls instead of rm
function ls() {
   for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++ )); do
      arg="${@:i:1}"
      echo "arg ${i}: ${arg}"
      [[ "${arg}" == \*.py ]] && { echo "Not allowed: ${arg}"; return 1; }
   done
   command ls "${@}"
   return 0
}

ls -a

ls -a *.py
```

Comment: you might want to use `builtin command ls "${@}"` in case command is aliased or overwritten by a function

Answer (score 0):

Correction to my ls function example:

```
[[ "${arg}" != \*.py ]] && [[ "${arg}" == *.py ]] && \
   { echo "Not allowed: ${arg}"; return 1; }
```

Then:

```
ls -a *.py

# ... and also play with modified shell wildcard expansion behaviour ...
( shopt -s nullglob; ls -a *.py )
```

Answer (score 0):

ThR37 says:

Here's a short python script based on the idea of simply wrapping command like "rm".
Bash wrapper are maybe a better idea but I like python :) :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=UTF-8

import getopt, sys
import subprocess
import re

exprs=[]
exprs.append(re.compile(".*\.py$"));
exprs.append(re.compile(".*\.cpp$"));
exprs.append(re.compile(".*\.hpp$"));
exprs.append(re.compile("\*$"));


def main():
        try:
            opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "Rrfiv", ["interactive","no-preserve-root","preserve-root","recursive","verbose","help","version"])
        except getopt.GetoptError, err:
            # print help information and exit:
            print str(err)
            usage()
        optsString = "".join([opt[0]+opt[1]+" " for opt in opts]);
        for arg in args:
            tab = [expr.match(arg) for expr in exprs];
            if  tab.count(None)!=len(tab):
                 print "Not removing "+str(arg);
            else
                cmd = ["/bin/rm"]+[opt[i] for opt in opts for i in range(2) if not opt[i]=='']+[str(arg)];
                rmfile = subprocess.Popen(cmd)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main();
```